# android creating word suggestion bar for suggesting my own words while typing

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to suggest my own words to user when user is typing on a `EditText`.
 
Is there any way to

1. inject my own words to soft keyboard of android?
2. or if it's no way how can I implement a bar of words on top of soft keyboard when user is typing?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve by using textChangeListener and a set of data to filter during typing

see link below
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html

Comment: I know I have to listen the text changes and respond to it, the question is using what UI layouts to make a floating bar upside of soft keyboard?